# mongodb java check if insert succeeded

Tags: java, mongodb

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient()
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb")
DBCollection recordsColl = db.getCollection("records")
BasicDBObject mongoRecord = new BasicDBObject()
//put some things in mongoRecord
recordsColl.insert(mongoRecord)
```

How can I tell if the insert went successfully?  Doing

```
WriteResult writeResult = recordsColl.insert(mongoRecord)
writeResult.getLastError()
```

Seems `getLastError()` has depreciated.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve that by setting the [write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) to an appropriate level.
By doing sth like

```
mongoClient.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);
```

before the write operation, an exception will be raised in case the write wasn't successful. Have a look at the Java driver docs for details.